# Rails Generate migration throwing error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, migration

i added a gem "acts-as-taggable-on" and when i ran the rails g acts_as_taggable_on:migration command. i got this 
Could not find generator 'acts_as_taggable_on:migration'. Maybe you meant 'active_record:migration', 'test_unit:integration' or 'migration'
Run `rails generate --help` for more options.
how to get this migration succesfull?

Comment: Just to be sure, did you run `bundle install` after adding the gem?

Comment: i already did that..

Comment: Did you run "rake acts_as_taggable_on_engine:install:migrations"  to install the generator first?

Comment: now i did that,thanks it works fine now..

Comment: i do have one bug though,i am declaring a attr_accessible :tag_list but it says exception caught when i run it in localhost